# getter and setter of JAVA platform

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm working on the JEE platform, and i do not understand why the getter and setter does not work for example No. 4

Is that it's not in compliance with the standard **lowerCamelCase**  becose the first two characters of the name are not both uppercase or lowercase.

Example 1 :

```
private Country country;

public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}
```

Example 2 :

```
private Country myCountry;

public Country getMyCountry() {
    return myCountry;
}

public void setMyCountry(Country myCountry) {
    this.myCountry = myCountry;
}
```

Example 3 :

```
private Country MyCountry;

public Country getMyCountry() {
    return MyCountry;
}

public void setMyCountry(Country MyCountry) {
    this.MyCountry = MyCountry;
}
```

Example 4 :

```
private Country aCountry;

public Country getaCountry() {
    return aCountry;
}

public void setaCountry(Country aCountry) {
    this.aCountry = aCountry;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: What exactly is the nature of this error? Do you expect different values/results, or do you get compilation/run time errors?

Also, are you sure you are calling the right methods? You are not accidentally calling `getMyCountry()`, for instance?

Comment: Note that the parameter name in the setter is irrelevant.

Comment: the getter setter for example 4 **does** work

Comment: This should "work" I am making some assumptions here but my guess is some library you are using is not working? 

That library / tool is probably not in compliance. When java decapitalizes variables if the first two characters are capitalized it does nothing. Which would not work for `getACountry` it would look for ACountry

Comment: @BlakeYarbrough the getter setter are not working for the 4th example.